# Is it a good approach to update the view in a scheduled timer or is it better to use OpenGL

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, opengl-es

I want some views bounce back at the edge of the screen. Therefore i already implemented a viewcontroller and some subviews for the bouncing. Its already known, when the view reaches the edge, all the Framecomparsion methods and exit angle methods are already known. But what is the best way for updating the views position. In the future, the rectangles should also bounce, when they reach eachother.

I tried to use +[UIView animation..] methods and it pretty much worked but the viewlayer position calculation was pretty hard to handle because its a timing calculation, when a view reaches the edge of the screen.

Than I tried to update the screen with a scheduled timer just like this:
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/30 target:self selector:@selector(render) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; //30 fps if possible b
But i just don't know if its a good approach for this, because I think, the battery gets drained too much, right?

Didn't get to learn OpenGL so far, but i might be pretty close, am i right?

What do you think, is the best way to solve this problem? If OpenGl is the best approach, is there a good tutorial you could suggest (i know, there are many, goolge is my friend, but i'd like to know from you).

Comment: You may want to take a look at SpriteKit, which is intended for exactly these kinds of things: Moving many elements around the screen, detecting collisions, etc. Caveat: SpriteKit is available only in iOS 7.

Comment: You could have a look about UIKit Dynamics in iOS7, using UIKit Dynamics,it very easy to simulate physical bounce back

Comment: Thanks you guys, but is there also a way for iOS 6. I'd like to support that version aswell.

Comment: I think you may should try to use CADisplayLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vincents comment, I ended up with his suggestion "I think you may should try to use CADisplayLink. –  Vincent"! I subclassed the GLKView and handle the reposition directly in the

```
- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


   [self updateViewPositions];
}
```

For those who are also struggling with a solution on iOS 6 and lower (min is iOS 5), i found [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1) tutorial with GLKView!